# d3js update pattern; chain-ed differently?

Tags: d3.js

I am trying to make a bunch of 0/1 svg text elements in a row which once clicked, flips.

I followed d3js update pattern, with `update()` on-click. It didn't work 
[shown here (live code on tributary)](http://tributary.io/inlet/0be371265abc909cd2e6).

Then I changed from this line

```
      t1.enter().append("text").attr("y",205).attr("x",function(d,i)  {return(40+i*80-4)}).text(function(d){return d})
```

.attr("fill", "red");

to that

```
t1.enter().append("text").attr("y",205).attr("x",function(d,i){return(40+i*80-4)});
t1.text(function(d){return d}).attr("fill", "red");
```

Now it worked [shown here (live code on tributary)](http://tributary.io/inlet/d59c75231f16a18dd673).

In other words, I broke the "chained" calls at `.text(function ...)`

But why, shouldn't they all return the same object in the chain?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the first code snippet, you are setting the text on the `enter` selection.  On each additional `update()` call, nothing enters the selection, therefore the text does not update.

In the second code snippet, you are correctly setting the text on the larger `update` selection.

*Note*, `t1` is the update selection.  `t1.enter()` is the enter selection.